# My browser is blank when I try displaying my html site

Tags: html, css

Uhm I am not experienced at asking for help other than to Chatgpt so bear with me.
Normally my html sites display correctly in the browser but this specific one just wont. It is just blank. I have tried everything chatgpt has thrown at me but nothing at all is happening. This is unusual as I normally fix the problem but this time I cant seem to figure out what is going on. Maybe it is because I am still beginner anyway. Lemme just show my code;

My code:

```css
/*styles.css:*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7), rgba(4,9,30,0.7), urL(siteimages/banner.png));
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>World University</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is also an image folder "siteimages" which is under the bigger project
By the way both these files and the image folder is in the same bigger project folder
I am trying to open the site locally

I have checked that everything is in the same directory
I have tried opening other html files and they do function properly
I have tried chrome and edge
Nothing shows up as error in the developer tools
I have used an online checker to proof-read my code and nothing bad shows up
Dont know what else to try

Just shoot everything at me please

Comment: What do you expect `linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7), rgba(4,9,30,0.7), urL(siteimages/banner.png))` to do? According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient), `linear-gradient()` doesn't accept an [`<image>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image).

Answer (score 0):

First try to change the urL by url, so without the L in captial.
Then, you just need to put the `url` part out of the `linear-radient` as:

```css
background: linear-gradient(
               rgba(4,9,30,0.7),
               rgba(4,9,30,0.7)
            ),
            url("https://www.yannickdixon.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/161124-golden-seaside-sunset-photography-print.jpg");
```

### DEMO

```css
/*styles.css:*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7), rgba(4,9,30,0.7)), url("https://www.yannickdixon.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/161124-golden-seaside-sunset-photography-print.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>World University</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```